# Duplicate a whole recordset based on an existing recordset

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a couple of tables with records associated with foreign keys. I would like to generate some testing data based on the existing records. Is there a best practice for writing SQL to duplicate the whole record set? The example below is for copying records from one table. What if I have multiple other tables linked to GAME? Can I use one statement to achieve that?

sql

```
INSERT INTO GAME (game_id, name, col_3) 
SELECT seq_game_id.nextval, name, col_3
FROM GAME 
WHERE NAME = 'Texas Holdem';
```

However, the requirement is to duplicate the entire record set, including related data across multiple tables. Manually performing this task would involve duplicating the 'GAME' table and all other related tables joined by the 'game_id.' These operations need to occur across multiple tables, with new rows added while maintaining relationships."

Comment: Of course you can. Just you a join query in insert.

Comment: As you can see from the very different answers, the description you have given is not really clear. Please edit your request and clarify how the tables are related and what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your problem is that

```
INSERT INTO GAME (game_id, name, col_3) 
SELECT seq_game_id.nextval, name, col_3
FROM GAME 
WHERE NAME = 'Texas Holdem';
```

generates new rows with new IDs. So if you want to duplicate rows from child tables, how to find the rows to copy and how to find the new associated ID?

```
INSERT INTO game_detail (game_detail_id, game_id, score) 
SELECT seq_game_detail_id.nextval, ???, score
--                                 ^^^-> which ID here?
FROM game_detail
WHERE game_id in (SELECT game_id FROM game WHERE name = 'Texas Holdem')
AND ??? -- how to exclude the newly created IDs?
;
```

We would need a reference telling us which new row stems from which old row.

You can do this with an interims table:

```
CREATE TABLE copy_info AS
SELECT game_id as old_id, seq_game_id.nextval AS new_id
FROM game
WHERE name = 'Texas Holdem';

INSERT INTO game (game_id, name, col_3) 
SELECT ci.new_id, g.name, g.col_3
FROM game g
JOIN copy_info ci ON ci.old_id = g.game_id;

INSERT INTO game_detail (game_detail_id, game_id, score) 
SELECT seq_game_detail_id.nextval, ci.new_id, gd.score
FROM game_detail gd
JOIN copy_info ci ON ci.old_id = gd.game_id;

DROP TABLE copy_info;
```

This works fine, as long as there are no grand child tables.

Another option is PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  v_new_game_id         game.game_id%TYPE;
  v_new_game_detail_id  game_detail.game_detail_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_game IN (SELECT * FROM game WHERE name = 'Texas Holdem') LOOP
    v_new_game_id := seq_game_id.nextval;

    INSERT INTO game (game_id, name, col_3)
    VALUES (v_new_game_id, rec_game.name, rec_game.col_3);

    FOR rec_game_detail IN (SELECT * FROM game_detail WHERE game_id = rec_game.game_id) LOOP
      v_new_game_detail_id := seq_game_detail_id.nextval;

      INSERT INTO game_detail (game_detail_id, game_id, score) 
      VALUES(v_new_game_detail_id, v_new_game_id, rec_game_detail.score;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a best practice for writing SQL to duplicate the whole record set?

If you want all the data from one table use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

or explicitly name the columns:

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, /* ..., */ columnN FROM table_name
```

If you also want to `INSERT` the data then you can use your query:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_table (otherColumn1, otherColumn2, /* ... */ otherColumnN)
SELECT column1, column2, /* ..., */ columnN FROM table_name;
```

Or, if there is existing data and you want to skip duplicates:

```sql
MERGE INTO test_table dst
USING table_name src
ON (dst.otherColumn1 = src.column1 AND dst.otherColumn2 = src.column2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (otherColumn1, otherColumn2, /* ..., */ otherColumnN)
  VAUES (column1, column2, /* ..., */ columnN);
```

*(If you want to update existing rows then you can also use a `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ...` clause.)*

> What if I have multiple other tables linked to GAME? Can I use one statement to achieve that?

Then use a `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT t1.column1,
       t1.column2,
       /* ..., */
       t1.columnN,
       t2.otherColumn1,
       t2.otherColumn2,
       /* ..., */
       t2.otherColumnN
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.column1 = t2.otherColumn1;
```

If you have more tables then use more `JOIN`s and if you want to `INSERT` that data then just prepend the `INSERT INTO` line before the `SELECT`.

If you want to `MERGE` with multiple tables then put the query which generates all the columns you want to insert into the `USING` clause:

```sql
MERGE INTO test_table dst
USING (
  SELECT t1.column1,
         t1.column2,
         /* ..., */
         t1.columnN,
         t2.otherColumn1,
         t2.otherColumn2,
         /* ..., */
         t2.otherColumnN
  FROM   table1 t1
         INNER JOIN table2 t2
         ON t1.column1 = t2.otherColumn1
) src
ON (dst.dstColumn1 = src.column1 AND dst.dstColumn2 = src.otherColumn2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (dstColumn1, dstColumn2, /* ..., */ dstColumnX)
  VAUES (column1, column2, /* ..., */ otherColumnN);
```

Comment: I suppose you have misunderstood the question. The question "The example below is for copying records from one table. What if I have multiple other tables linked to GAME?" seems to mean that the game table has child tables (i.e. tables that contain a game_id). So how not only to duplicate game table rows, but include all their child table rows in the duplication process?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You seem to have missed the second half of my answer where I mention using `JOIN`s. The OP does not explain that they have multiple destination tables, only multiple source tables (you appear to have made that assumption just like I made the assumption that because they didn't mention inserting into multiple destination tables, that they were not doing so).

Comment: Ah, okay, you are right. That is not clear. I still find my interpretation more likely :-)